# creating a struct to map binary data

Tags: c++, struct

Assuming I have this binary data:

```
'01 00 00 00' '02' '65 66 00' '05 00 00 00'
```

The first 4 bytes is an `int` the other byte in sequence represents the length of the ASCII string that will follow next, and after the string there is another `int`
In 010 Template editor I can do structs like this, that will suit this binary data completely:

```
struct Mapped{
int FirstInt;
byte StringLength;
char String[StringLength]; // compiler does not like this
int SecondInt;
};
```

But I can't do this in C++. Im my code, I only have a `char*` that I want to make: `Mapped* friendlyData = (Mapped*)sourceBuffer;` and then access that string and every other data after it.

How can I do this? I tried using `std::string` instead of the combination of `byte StringLength` and `char String[StringLength]` but it didn't work aswell.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is your string variable length? If so show how you tried to read it because maybe there is a bug with how you are reading the variable length binary string.

Comment: Yes the string is variable length, but I can't define it in the struct as `char String[StringLength];` it gives me error.

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting. You might want to use a vector of chars and and poll the size of the vector for StringLength. Is that possible in this use case? Otherwise, you might want an external function that would trim String to StringLength if you are unable to embed it in the struct, and just declare it as a pointer of chars.

Comment: If I just declare it as a `char*` it would only take 4 bytes in the struct. Thus, every other data after it, would become incorrect... can you see what I mean?

Comment: You can't have a variable-size struct field, full stop. (Unless it's the last one in the struct, if your compiler supports that as an extension, and in that case the compiler still won't know the size so you won't be able to use `+1` to get a pointer to the next struct)